# How to use scanf in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, scanf

I'm new to the kernel programming. When i try to use scanf in my character device file code, i'm getting this error message
:error: implicit declaration of function ‘scanf’

How can i solve this problem ? Please help me out.

I'm using linux CentOS in virtual box.

Comment: You shouldn't be using any of the `*scanf` functions *at all* -- even when you're not programming in kernel mode.

Answer (score 7):

Because the kernel does not have a "standard input" or "open files", it makes no sense for there to be a `scanf()` function available. (Okay, the BSD process accounting is a place where the kernel does have a file open. But the kernel *writes* this file.)

The replacement you are looking for is named either `sscanf()` or `vsscanf()`, both are defined in `lib/vsprintf.c`:

```
/**
 * vsscanf - Unformat a buffer into a list of arguments
 * @buf:    input buffer
 * @fmt:    format of buffer
 * @args:   arguments
 */
int vsscanf(const char *buf, const char *fmt, va_list args)

/**
 * sscanf - Unformat a buffer into a list of arguments
 * @buf:    input buffer
 * @fmt:    formatting of buffer
 * @...:    resulting arguments
 */
int sscanf(const char *buf, const char *fmt, ...)
```

Which one you pick depends upon how you would rather call it. The source for `sscanf()` shows how to use the `vssanf()` function, in case you'd rather use the varargs calling convention.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use libc functions in the kernel. Pure C only. I am sure someone can provide the kernel equivalent.

Comment: Although this is not strictly wrong, there are many functions available in the kernel which have the same names and parameters as libc functions.